# What is difference between malloc() and realloc()?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

Suppose I've two code samples for creating an integer array of 10 elements:

```
 int *pi = (int*) 0x000; //base ADDRESS of OS
    realloc(pi,10);
```

and the other is the one that is written normally, i.e.:

```
int *pi;
pi=(int*) malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

Now, my question is: The first type of assignment is legal but not used. Why?
And what is the difference between them?

Comment: first of all it's not [tag:c++] specific.

Comment: funnily enough, it seems to be very close to an exact duplicate of the question above, looks like copied!

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: The equivalent call is `realloc(pi, 10 * sizeof(int))`

The realloc doc explains that the call, in your specific case, is the same as a malloc:

> If ptr is NULL, realloc() is identical to a call to malloc() for size bytes.

Comment: you cannot use realloc first time on a pointer.

First you create a pointer then you can alloc it with a memory address.

Answer (score 3):

`realloc` may extend, shrink or not change allocated memory segment. Depending on implementation, it may be more efficient than allocating new block and copying old content (possibly partial) and deleting old one.

Other than that, `realloc` over null pointer should have exactly the same outcome and performance as `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

`0x000` is not the base address of OS, it's the integer `0`, the compiler will convert it to a null pointer. So the first piece of code is the same as:

```
int *pi = realloc(NULL,10);
```

It has the same effect of

```
int *pi = malloc(10);
```

Note that it's not the same as your second example because of lack of `sizeof(int)`.

The reason people normally don't use `realloc` in this case is simply that `malloc` can do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `realloc()` function want's it's first parameter to be a pointer that was obtained with a formerly issued call to `malloc()`. It allocates a new memory block and frees the formerly allocated memory block.

If you pass `NULL` to `realloc()` it behaves the same way as `malloc()`.